# What is the Ruby ActiveRecord equivalent for this SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, activerecord

What would be an optimized (fast) ActiveRecord equivalent in Ruby:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers.city 
FROM customers
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT c_id 
  FROM carts
  WHERE shop_id = #{`shop_id`}
  ORDER BY created_at DESC 
  LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000
) AS filtered_carts ON customers.id = filtered_carts.c_id;
```

Note: `shop_id` is a ruby variable passed to the query/association.
Thank you

This above SQL runs as fast as expected.

I am trying to find a pure ActiveRecord solution to avoid something like this:

```
customers = Customer
  .select(:city)
  .distinct
  .joins("
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT c_id
      FROM carts
      WHERE shop_id = #{`shop_id`}
      ORDER BY created_at DESC
      LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000
    ) AS filtered_carts
    ON customers.id = filtered_carts.c_id
  ")
```

The reason is to avoid having hardcoded SQL in the ActiveRecord to prevent possible future issues with backward compatibility of eventual model chages and migrations...

Comment: Why do you do `OFFSET 1000`?

Comment: It was just arbitrary to show an effort to slice the job into many parts (`offset` and `limit`). I am trying to figure out a solution for both a thousand and one million records

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you do not need the `JOIN` at all. A subquery in the `where` should be enough:

```
customer_ids = 
  Cart
    .select(:c_id)
    .where(shop_id: shop_id)
    .order(:created_at)
    .limit(1000)
    .offset(1000)

Customer
  .where(id: customer_ids)
  .distinct
  .pluck(:city)
```

Note that the `customer_ids` is only a `ActiveRecord::Relation` and that the query is not run immediately. It is only run as subquery when the second query is executed.

Comment: Thank you - one question - if you have more than 1 million customer records, how would that affect the Ruby/ActiveRecord performance (passing a hash, string or array with so many records)? This implies removing `offset` and `limit` from the query

Comment: That depends on many factors: The specs of the database server, how well indexes are set on the database tables, memory of your application server, how big the records are. Therefore, I cannot give a good answer to that question. You simply have to try it out. In general, a subquery is likely more performant than a join, but the more records match the query the slower the response will be, the more memory the servers will require to perform the query.

Comment: @spickermann would a `WHERE EXIST(...)` be faster then `WHERE "customers"."id" IN(...)`?

Comment: @max Just did quick research on that topic. And it seems like it depends on the size of the sub-query and on the specific implementation in the database.